# Injective function from N (naturals) to Q?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vp570S6Plt8) at 11:17, the speaker says that their argument proves that the size of infinity of Q is less than the size of infinity of N. This makes sense to me, as in the diagram they drew, assuming I am understanding correctly, a line emanating from the origin will represent a certain slope, and that given slope will then map to more and more integer coordinates the farther out it goes, and assuming it continues infinitely, an infinite number of natural numbers should correspond to a particular rational number.

But then, the speaker proceeds to say that since there is also an injective function the other way (from N to Q), the size of infinity of N must be less than the size of infinity of Q; therefore, they must be the same size. This reasoning does not make sense to me. For one, how is it possible to make an injective function from N to Q when there are infinitely many natural numbers in your domain that would correspond to a single rational number output Q? You would surely have infinitely many natural numbers left over if you tried to make a one-to-one correspondence between N and Q, and that would then not be an injective function; it seems simply impossible that you could match each N to a unique Q. And how would you conclude from there that since N is less than Q one way and Q is less than N another way, that they must be the same size?

I am aware of Cantor's matching up of the rationals with the natural numbers or integers, and so I understand that they are both of equal cardinality (countably infinite). I simply do not understand the argument presented in this video, even after hours and hours of contemplation and searching. As I am relatively new to set theory, a less rigorous explanation would probably be easier for me to follow, but I would regardless be enormously grateful if anyone could clarify this for me. Thank you!

Comment: suggestion: delete question and study Related material...

Comment: Your objection is nonsensical. There are maps from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ where each natural is matched to a single rational, and different naturals matched to different rationals. Whee does this "infinitely many natural numbers in your domain that would correspond to a single rational output" nonsense come from? The map that sends the natural number $n$ to the rational number $\frac{n}{1}$ does not have the alleged infirmity, for instance. Why do you assume the problem must manifest?

Comment: I'm sorry that this sounds nonsensical, it just seemed that way from the diagram shown in the video. Again, I know very little about set theory, and am just coming from that video. It seemed that the speaker's diagram was saying that any line emanating from the origin in a Z x Z plane would represent a particular rational number slope, and that if you labeled points in the plane with a unique natural number and continued on forever, the slope would then pass through an infinite number of some integer points and thus an infinite number of some natural numbers? I thought that was what it meant.

Comment: C'mon folks. Try to be a bit nicer. Clearly the OP is struggling and insults are not beneficial...

Comment: The function you describe is meant to show you have an embedding from rationals to naturals. It is not meant to **also** be a function embedding naturals into rationals.You quote it as saying "there is **also**" a function embedding naturals into the rationals, i.e., a *different* function (presumably the obvious one I already described), *not* the one that went the other way,sending each rational to the label of the first point the corresponding line "hits".

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you!